# How to finalize a model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a straightforward model developed in Keras:

```
....
model = Model(input, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
graph.finalize()

history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=30)
```

Since I'm dealing with some memory leak problems, it seemed like a good idea to finalize the graph to prevent the mentioned issue. But when I do, I get an exception `RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train.py", line 43, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=30)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 157, in model_iteration
    f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 532, in _make_execution_function
    return model._make_execution_function(mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2276, in _make_execution_function
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2212, in _make_train_function
    if not isinstance(K.symbolic_learning_phase(), int):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 299, in symbolic_learning_phase
    False, shape=(), name='keras_learning_phase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2159, in placeholder_with_default
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6406, in placeholder_with_default
    "PlaceholderWithDefault", input=input, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 527, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 290, in _constant_impl
    name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3588, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3225, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

There's nothing custom in this model, all the layers are from Keras library. And I'm using Tensorflow 1.14 and the Keras that comes with it (`tensorflow.keras`).

My question is, what are my options here? How can I pinpoint the reason for graph change? Or maybe I'm finalizing the graph wrong!?

**[UPDATE]**

To make sure that the problem is not with my setup and model, I followed the example provided in [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) (follow [the Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate.ipynb)). I just added the two lines of code to finalize the graph just before calling the fit method. And I faced the same error. So my question stands, how do you finalize a model in Keras?

Comment: Maybe Keras is finalizing the graph before you did it in the `model.compile()` method?

Comment: as you can see the fit() method is indirectly using the _check_not_finalized() method that raises the exception you are getting. this is because the fit() method actually modifies the tf graph if I'm not going wrong. When I use the finalize() method for concurrent predict()-ions I first have to run a dummy predict() to let it modify the graph, then I finalize() the graph and finally I start the other threads, once the graph is finalized. Try the same: run first a dummy fit(), finalize() the graph, and then start working on it.